# Laravel login flow

Tags: laravel, authentication

When using default auth scaffold from Laravel, at register the password is hashed with bcrypt in RegisterController.php under create function

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I would like to know where is the function that hashes the user input for password at login? It must be somewhere built inside vendor folder but i can't find it.

So when the user want's to login he enters the plain text password and this plain text gets hashed again with bcrypt and then compared with saved and hashed password in DB. But where does laravel make this? In which function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Laravel never decrypts your password**

Bcrypt passwords in `Laravel` are never decrypted, the password entered by the user just gets compared to the already hashed password stored in the database.

Update:

If you are authenticating using Eloquents User Model;

*vendor/laravel/ framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php*

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];
    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

If you are authenticating the Database driver;

*vendor/laravel/ framework//src/Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php*

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];
    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

Comment: @lewis4u It is not encrypted again. It is `hashed`, there is a big difference.

Comment: OK let's start again....the users password is hashed at register and saved like so in DB...then on login user writes password at login form and that what he wrote in password field gets hashed again with bcrypt and gets compared with the password in DB....and that function i want to see!!

Comment: Yes that is what happens, and look at my update. It will show you the logic after the bcrypt() helper function in laravel.

Comment: yes...i see how the text gets hashed with bcrypt...but that is not the answer to my question...i have updated it...can you see please.

Comment: i found the route now...  POST     | login                  |       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login

Comment: but it's empty...and login function in AuthenticatesUsers.php is confusing

Comment: It is using the AutenticatesUsers trait, because of that all the functions defined in that trait are available from that controller. Of course it's a little confusing, you are diving in the source code of how everything works inside the framework. It is however a very good thing to do and you'll learn how the framework handles stuff behind the scenes

Comment: Yes i want to learn and i still didn't find the moment when this user password gets hashed on login

Comment: It is the function provided in the answer link. When you call the `bcrypt()` helper function Laravel will internally call the `make` function in the `BcryptHasher` class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125573/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-jhonny-walker).

Answer (score 0):

`bcrypt` is the function that turns it into hash. It is a one way hash algo and can't be decrypted. The password that user sends in plain text, convert that using `bcrypt` and then compare in db.

Comment: OK but can you help me to find where is the login function flow

Comment: I found some possible locations: Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

Comment: Please mention the name of the function and Laravel version.

Comment: there is validateLogin((Request $request) and login(Request $request) function inside